# Showing regions with minimum width in an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

**Hi!**

I'm following a paper to implement ***automatic road extraction from aerial images***.

Approach which is being followed is finding reference circles and central pixels.

I've found central pixels using regional maxima now I've to find regions with minimum width using radius of reference circles which is simple distance of central pixels.

Following is my matlab code till now

```
I=imread('road_3.jpg');
imshow(I)
I_gray=rgb2gray(I);
I_gray=imresize(I_gray,[500 500]);
I_edge=edge(I_gray,'canny');
I_dist=bwdist(I_edge); %this will give me distance transform image 
I_cp=imregionalmax(I_dist); %this will give me central pixels
c=sum(sum(I_cp)); %counting total number of central pixels
for i=1:500
for j=1:500
if(I_cp(i,j)==1)
count=count+1;
x_cp(count)=i; %saving X index of Central pixel
y_cp(count)=j; %saving Y index of Central pixel
end
end
end
for i=1:c
radius_cp(x_cp(i),y_cp(i))=I_dist(x_cp(i),y_cp(i)); % saving radius of each central pixel as it is its distance.
end
AllRadius=radius_cp(radius_cp>0); %it is for our convenience so, minimum or maximum or any radius could be fetched
```

now, we've grey scale image, edge image, distance transform image, central pixels image.

I want to find:

*1. Regions with minimum width using radius.*

*2. Plotting reference circles.*

Here there is a example image:
[image]

More examples can be viewed [here](http://1drv.ms/1lZpXLI).

Hopefully my question is cleared and not ambiguous.

Seeing forward for +ve response.

**Thank you.**

**regard:**

**Syed Meesum Ali.**

Comment: please post an example images and intermediate results as well.

Comment: its asking for atleast 10 reputations for posting image so, i'm sharing onedrive's link.


https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9677E9D69DEC9FBA!1519&authkey=!AFkVrFoasUWq0OU&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.jpg

Comment: @Shai any help you could do now as i've shared images from onedrive. And also i want to do line fitting on edge image and central pixel image.

Comment: I really cannot tell anything just from the edge mask. Please post: original input image, edge image, distance transform image, and central pixel image. Can you also draw by hand what you would like the algorithm to detect - what is the desired output for you - this can help us understand your question better.

Comment: @Shai hopefully this will help you...here is a public link to all 5 images... [link](http://1drv.ms/1lZpXLI)

Comment: [Research paper](http://www.waset.org/publications/1932) which is being followed by me.